# How to get Facebook permissions for app

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions, status

I'm trying to get read_stream and rsvp_event permissions but FB's staff continue rejecting my submissions .. Why is so tricky retrieving permissions for a simple app?

I just need to read my status messages and events and display it on my website.

How do you create permissions submissions for your FB apps?

(I use graph api on my php site)

Answer (score 1):

This is from the docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1#reference-read_stream

> This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example, Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In addition, Web, Desktop and TV apps will not be granted this permission.

So, it's very unlikely that you get this permission approved.

Regarding the events, I think `user_events` would be the right one: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1#reference-user_events

As I understand this is only for the use on your personal website, why don't you generate the Access Token for your user manually via the Graph API Explorer, prolongue it and store it somewhere in your PHP script? You'll need to update the Access Token every 60 days manually as well, but this I think the most pragmatic option you have.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending

Comment: thx for your informations, yes what I need is just user_status and user_events, btw how can I update the access token manually without going on the graph api explorer and click on the "get access token" every time?

Comment: @Luke: By implementing proper login flow as described in the documentation …

Comment: @CBroe That's true :-) But if it's only for him, I'm not sure whether it's worth the overhead...